# Gradle failling after update to buildTools 27.0.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

After updating to build tools 27.0.3, my build stopped working with a NullPointerException.

```
$ ./gradlew main:build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :main 
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to notify task execution graph listener.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

fullstacktrace: https://gist.github.com/plentz/59b676fc86dd4c3bfe2333c89b82c506

build.gradle: https://gist.github.com/plentz/eac62d1c5d207affba6153b0efb2e1ca

Comment: Clear cachés and restart

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` files here and your fill stracktrace.

Comment: @JaredBurrows done

Comment: You have not posted your `build.gradle` or the stacktrace in this question yet.

Comment: @JaredBurrows they're links right in the end of the question...

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing this issue on **AGP 3.1.0** and **3.1.1**. I downgraded the plugin to **3.0.0** to fix this issue, but with a second thought, just decided to go on with using Android Studio 3.2 canary build with **AGP 3.2.0 alpha**, where the issue seems to be resolved.

The bug seems to be fixed somewhere during the alpha revisions, so just go on with the latest, which is AGP 3.2.0-alpha10 for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `your_project_path/.gradle` then restart Android studio and re-compile the project

Comment: add log from `./gradlew main:build --stacktrace`

Comment: just added a gist with it https://gist.github.com/plentz/59b676fc86dd4c3bfe2333c89b82c506

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue but what I am noticing is that this is not due to build tools version but due to AGP version 3.1.0 and 3.1.1. Lowering it to 3.0.0 removed the issue for now.